# How to store/retrieve List<string> values from/to database using java

Tags: java, database, eclipse, oracle-sqldeveloper, soapui

so I'd like to know how can i **store** List in one field in database and the type of that field is **VARCHAR2**
and after that i want to **retrieve** them later to get it in response.

basically my project go like that SoapUI Request ==> Eclipse ==> SQLDeveloper ==> Eclipse ==> SoapUI Response

i have a class that has the definition of the list like that

```
private String name;
private int number;
private List<String>channel;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
   this.name= name;
}
public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(int number) {
   this.number= number;
}
public String getChannel() {
    return channel;
}
public void setChannel(List<String>channel) {
   this.channel= channel; 
}
```

and it is getting the list that i inserted in the request 
Ex: [a,b,c,d]
now i have a problem in storing them in database using stored procedure

```
database.AddInParameter("NAME",request.getName());
database.AddInParameter("NUMBER",request.getNumber());
database.AddInParameter("CHANNEL",request.setChannel());//it crashes here and it is returning NULL
database.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and i am getting the data from database like

```
while (rs.next())
{
save.setName(rs.getName());
save.setNumber(rs.getNumber());
save.setChannel(rs.getChannel());
}
```

I am missing something ?
can someone tell me how to fix it and how can i retrieve the list as a list?

Comment: You don't store a list in a varchar. You store a single string in a varchar. Create an additional table with two columns: a foreign key to your main table, and a varchar. If the order of the elements in the list is important, you'l need a third column to store the index. Store each element of the list as a row of this new table. And please, respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Agree with @JBNizet, but depending on your actual scenario, you could store the list values as a comma-separated string in a VARCHAR, assuming combined value length will always fit in a single VARCHAR, and assuming values don't have commas. Better to store in sub-table suggested by JB.

Answer (score 0):

As far as ORM, one option would be to create a relation to a table called Channel.

That way each name/number object has a relationship to result of channels from the channel table.

This also keeps the repeating of channels in the database.